# How to prevent Imagick morph from overlapping transparent PNG in layers

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm using a simple morph on imagick from one image to another. This are my initial images:

[image]

I am using imagick to morph (interpolate frames) with this code:

```
$images = [

    "tentacle 10.png",
    "tentacle 23.png",

];

$imagick = new \Imagick();

foreach ($images as $image) {       
    $nextImage = new \Imagick($image);
    $imagick->addImage($nextImage);
}

$imagick->resetIterator();
$morphed = $imagick->morphImages(1);
```

The end result is this:

[image]

As you can see, the later frames overlap the previous frames, but since they have a transparent background, the back image also appears.

When I convert the initial images to .jpg, losing the transparent background, it works normally and does not overlap frames. This is the result:

[image]

How to get this working for transparent images?